# Linked list in C with fgets()

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I'm having issues with my code skipping the first question in the second data structure. I'm pretty sure it's because the gets(), but not sure. I think I tried fgets(), but it still was giving me issues. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NumberOfActresses 5

typedef struct Actress
{
char *name, *placeofbirth, *haircolor;
int age;
float networth;
struct Actress *next;

} Actress;

void PopulateStruct(Actress *node)
{
node->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
node->placeofbirth = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
node->haircolor = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);

printf("Please enter the name of the actress/actor: ");
gets(node->name);
printf("Please enter the actress/actor place of birth: ");
gets(node->placeofbirth);
printf("Please enter the actress/actor hair color: ");
gets(node->haircolor);
printf("Please enter the actress/actor age: ");
scanf("%d", &node->age);
printf("Please enter the actress/actor networth: ");
scanf("%f", &node->networth);
}

void DisplayStruct(Actress *head)
{
Actress *crawler;

crawler = head;

while(crawler != NULL)
{
    printf("The name of the actress/actor is: %s\n", crawler->name);
    printf("The place of birth for the actress/actor is: %s\n",       crawler->placeofbirth);
    printf("The hair color of the actress/actor is: %s\n", crawler->haircolor);
    printf("The actress/actor age is: %d\n", crawler->age);
    printf("The networth for the actress/actor is %f\n", crawler->networth);
    crawler = crawler->next;
}
}

int main()
{
int i;
Actress *head = (Actress *) malloc(sizeof(Actress)), *crawler;

crawler = head;

 for (i = 0; i < NumberOfActresses; i++)
    {
    PopulateStruct(crawler);
    if (i == 2)
        crawler->next = NULL;
    else
        crawler->next = malloc(sizeof(Actress));

    crawler = crawler->next;
}

crawler = NULL;

DisplayStruct(head);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%f", &node->networth);` --> `scanf("%f%*c", &node->networth);` `%*c` consume remaining newline. Also `if (i == 2)` --> `if (i == 4)` ?

Comment: Mixing `fgets` and `scanf` always turns out badly. And using `gets` is just plain wrong.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Apologies, the if statement is supposed to read if(I == NumberOfActresses - 1). Using the %*c will fix this issue or should I use something else?

Comment: @user3386109 So what should I use?

Comment: I think that works as expected. If by force say, Ensure the memory is better to release (`free`'ed).

Comment: @MichaelBenton I converted the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing `fgets` and `scanf` always turns out badly. The reason is that `scanf` will leave the newline character in the input stream, and the following `fgets` will therefore read an empty line. And using `gets` is [just plain wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036).

The solution is to always read the input with `fgets`, and then parse the input with `sscanf` as needed. For those cases where `sscanf` is not needed, i.e. the input is a string, you can use `strcspn` to remove the newline from the buffer.

```
int PopulateStruct(Actress *node)
{
    char buffer[100];

    printf("Please enter the name of the actress/actor: ");
    if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) == NULL )
        return 0;
    buffer[strcspn(buffer,"\n")] = '\0';
    if ( (node->name = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1)) == NULL )
        return 0;
    strcpy( node->name, buffer );

    // ditto for place of birth and hair color

    printf("Please enter the actress/actor age: ");
    if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) == NULL )
        return 0;
    if ( sscanf( buffer, "%d", &node->age ) != 1 )
        return 0;

    printf("Please enter the actress/actor networth: ");
    if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) == NULL )
        return 0;
    if ( sscanf( buffer, "%lf", &node->networth ) != 1 )
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Oh, and I changed the `networth` from `float` to `double`. A `float` has only 6 or 7 digits of precision, and that's not nearly enough for the net worth of an actress/actor.